# Can't connect to Postgres server

Tags: postgresql, fedora, postgresql-9.4

I am attempting to run `pg_basebackup` in order to create a slave server, but I keep getting this error:

```
pg_basebackup: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: No route to host
    Is the server running on host "192.168.1.164" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

On the `192.168.1.164` server, the `postgresql.conf` file has:

```
listen_addresses = '*' # originally 'localhost, 192.168.1.63'
port = 5432
```

and the `pg_hba.conf` file has:

```
host    replication     replicator      192.168.1.63/32 md5
```

where `192.168.1.63` is the slave server.

The link between the two machines is fine since I can SSH from either one to the other using those IPs. Also, the `service postgresql` is `start`ed on the master, and `stop`ed on the slave. The master has a Postgres user `replicator`.

I am running both machines with PostgreSQL 9.4.4 and Fedora 22.

EDIT: from the master's psql, running `SHOW config_file;` and `SHOW hba_file;` matches with the files I've been editing, and of course, the server was restarted after the edits.

Comment: You would have better chance on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out this was a firewall issue. The solution is this:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=5432/tcp
firewall-cmd --add-port=5432/tcp
```

Note: I came from Ubuntu which doesn't have this port blocked, so I didn't realize it needed to be opened up.

Comment: Test it with the telnet, if connect dicart firewall, if not may be firewall or network.